# Is there any way to create a class diagram for my class in eclipse?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I'm using eclipse to program my java exercises for my CSCI class. Is there any way eclipse can give me a class diagram for a class that I've created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a plug-in, like this [one](http://jupe.binaervarianz.de/), currently in alpha stage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way that Eclipse can generate a UML diagram, but it does give a very useful outline of the code on the side. Hope you find an alternative!

EDIT: now that you got me interested, I did a little research.  Check out [this website](http://www.vogella.de/articles/UML/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try Fujaba for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Might help : http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/